DELTA LIVE TABLES - apply_changes from source dataset not working
I am using delta live tables in medallion architecture.
I have:

columns: id, timestamp, operation, deleted_flag
operations "Insert" and "delete"

When the operation is "insert" the deleted_flag will be null and for "delete" it will be yes. This is correctly populating in bronze table. but for silver table i am taking bronze table as source and performing apply_changes. But after that for series of insert and delete operations for same id , if last operation is "insert" then the deleted flag should be  null. But i am getting as yes. Can someone please help me. I don't want to delete old records in silver table
I want the deleted_flag to be null for last insert if there are a series of inserts and deleted for same id. and if last operation is delete then it should be "yes"

Create transactional log table
dlt.apply_changes(
target = f"{table_name}",
source = f"{source_table_name}",
keys = [f"{keys}"],
sequence_by = col(f"{sequence_key}").desc(),
#apply_as_deletes = expr("__OPERATION = 'DELETE'"),            # TODO: Revisit this one. We should be able to see deleted events in silver history
ignore_null_updates = True,
stored_as_scd_type = "2"
)

As far as I can tell, it seems like you would be able to do some simple transformations on your source data before running apply_changes, something like below. I've only handled the case for the inserts showing deletions as NULL but you should be able to expand on this.
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (
    dlt.read(f"{source_table_name}"
        .withColumn('deleted_flag ', F.when(F.col('operation') == 'insert', F.lit(None), F.col('deleted_flag')
)


# YOUR ORIGINAL CODE BELOW
# Create transactional log table 

dlt.apply_changes(target = f"{table_name}", 
                  source = df, 
                  keys = [f"{keys}"], sequence_by = col(f"{sequence_key}").desc(), 
                  #apply_as_deletes = expr("__OPERATION = 'DELETE'"), # TODO: Revisit this one. We should be able to see deleted events in silver history 
                  ignore_null_updates = True, 
                  stored_as_scd_type = "2" )

